# Does JavaScript have a method like Ruby's 'tr' method?

Tags: javascript

Does JavaScript have a method like [Ruby's `tr` method](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr)?

```
string.tr('0123456789','9876543210')
```

Comment: no, but it's easy to write

Comment: when I say easy ... depends on how much of `tr` you want to implement :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation I just threw together now

As far as I know, it follows the ruby implementation

Several things I don't know about ruby implementation are

1. What if the from or to string contains a trailing or leading dash?
2. What if you put a range like 9-0, i.e high to low?
3. If from starts with `^` and to is more than one character, should that be an error? or just use the first character ignoring the rest?

This code simply uses dash as a dash if it's the first or last in the string, and `9-0` will become `9876543210`

Anyway, hopefully this is enough

```js
const tr = (str, from, to) => {
    const fixupDash = s => {
        const range = (l, h) => {
            // let's assume a dash in the first or last position is a literal dash
            if (typeof l !== 'string' || typeof h !== 'string') {
                return l || h;
            }
            l = l.charCodeAt(0);
            h = h.charCodeAt(0);
            let sgn = Math.sign(h-l);
            l += sgn;
            h -= sgn;
            return Array.from({length:Math.abs(h-l)+1}, (_, i) => String.fromCharCode(sgn * i + l)).join('');
        }
        return s.split('').map((c, i, a) => c === '-' ? range(a[i-1], a[i+1]) : c).join('');
    }
    from = fixupDash(from);
    to = fixupDash(to).padEnd(from.length, to[to.length-1]);
    if (from[0] !== '^') {
        const mapper = Object.assign({}, ...from.split('').map((f, i) => ({[f]: to[i]})));
        return str.split('').map(c => mapper.hasOwnProperty(c) ? mapper[c] : c).join('');
    } else {
        to = to[0];
        const mapper = Object.assign({}, ...from.split('').map((f, i) => ({[f]: f})));
        return str.split('').map(c => mapper.hasOwnProperty(c) ? mapper[c] : to).join('');
    }
};

// not recommended, but you can if you want, then you can "hello".tr('el', 'ip')
String.prototype.tr = function(from, to) {
    return tr(this, from, to);
};
console.log("hello".tr('el', 'ip'))      //#=> "hippo"
console.log("hello".tr('aeiou', '*'))    //#=> "h*ll*"
console.log("hello".tr('a-y', 'b-z'))    //#=> "ifmmp"
console.log("hello".tr('^aeiou', '*'))   //#=> "*e**o"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have find the answer , hope help someone who want implement this function:

```
function tr (str, from, to) {
var out = "", i, m, p ;
for (i = 0, m = str.length; i < m; i++) {
p = from.indexOf(str.charAt(i));
if (p >= 0) {
out = out + to.charAt(p);
}
else {
out += str.charAt(i);
}
}
return out;
}
```

Comment: `tr('hello', 'a-y', 'b-z') === "ifmmp"`? `tr('hello', '^aeiou', '*')  === "*e**o"`? both fail - see [documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr)

Answer (score -2):

can you try the

```
string.replace()
```

Here is the link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

```js
var str = "hello world";
var subString = "hello";
var newSubstring = "girl";

var newString = str.replace(subString, newSubstring);

console.log(newString);
```

Comment: this produces nothing like what `tr` does

Comment: but we can use it to write the function like tr :)

Comment: replace wouldn't be my first choice to be honest - far easier using split/map/join